# cross-origin error when using color-thief

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm not gonna lie, cross-origin is not very clear to me although I've read some articles about it.

I was trying to fetch songs from an api which does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` meeans i couldn't get the data inside my app. I went to google, stackoverflow, read some articles and used the `proxy: "https://www.jiosaavn.com"` in package.json which i got in this article: https://medium.com/swlh/avoiding-cors-errors-on-localhost-in-2020-5a656ed8cefa

It did fix my issue, api requests are working fine.

But now I want to add [color-thief](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/color-thief/) to my app.

I made a [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70548107/colorthief-js-colorthief-is-not-a-function-error) about it. It works when I use image from sources like unsplash and pexels with attribute `crossOrigin={anonymous}` on the image HTML element like this

```
<img
        crossOrigin={anonymous}
        ref={imgRef}
        style={{width:"400px", objectFit: "contain"}}
        src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1534411/pexels-photo-1534411.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-shukhrat-umarov-1534411.jpg&fm=jpg"
        alt="landscape"
        onLoad={() => {
          const colorThief = new ColorThief();
          const img = imgRef.current;
          const result = colorThief.getColor(img, 25);
          console.log(result);
        }}
/>
```

But adding `crossOrigin={anonymous}` makes the image fail to load (which I'm getting from the api).

---

If you're wondering why I didn't use it like this:

```
<img
            src={currentSong.image}
            ref={imgRef}
            alt="Songimg"
            onLoad={() => {
              const colorThief = new ColorThief();
              const img = imgRef.current;
              const result = colorThief.getColor(img, 25);
              console.log(result);
            }}
          />
```

then, it shows me this:

```
SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data
```

Comment: The documentation for Color Thief explains this: when you load an image from a domain that does not allow cross-origin access, the image is marked as "tainted" in the browser and tools like Color Thief are disallowed from examining the contents of the images.

Comment: So, ig there is no way I can use colorthief in my app?

Comment: As the documentation suggests, you have to proxy access to the images with a server in your own domain, or a server that sets the CORS headers properly.

Comment: At first I thought that creating img element in the DOM with the help of the proxy and then accessing it via useRef Hook would work, but for some reason it shows this gives me naturalWidth err, idk what that means but i can't understand why is this happening.

Comment: The error is not about `naturalWidth` itself, it's about `img` being `null`, which means that `imgRef` is not properly set up.

Comment: Yeah, now i fixed the ```img``` with useRef properly. Then this error comes ```SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.```

Comment: Right, that's the sign that the image source (the website where the image is hosted) is not setting CORS headers, so it's time to use a proxy to fetch the image.

Comment: And how to do that? I'm already using proxy in my app as stated above.

Comment: I don't know how the proxy mechanism you're using is supposed to work. You can use the browser "Network" debugging tool to examine the requests, but if you're getting that error it means that the CORS headers are not present, and also that the source domain of the image is not your own domain.